# Google Drive API service->files->get('root') fails with "file not found.' (Scopes problem?)

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-oauth, scopes

I have a PHP script that fails (404, [file] not found) when the following  code is executed:

```
$result = $service->changes->getStartPageToken() ;
$nextStartPageToken = $result->startPageToken ;
$rootResult = $service->files->get('root')
```

The the failure is at that last line, and the error log says:

```
[13-Aug-2023 20:24:47 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "File not found: 0AORSlah_iew_Uk9PVA.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "File not found: 0AORSlah_iew_Uk9PVA.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound",
        "location": "fileId",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}
 in /www/cgi-bin/GoogleRelated/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php:134
Stack trace:
#0 /www/cgi-bin/GoogleRelated/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php(107): Google\Http\REST::decodeHttpResponse()
#1 [internal function]: Google\Http\REST::doExecute()
#2 /www/cgi-bin/GoogleRelated/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Task/Runner.php(187): call_user_func_array()
#3 /www/cgi-bin/GoogleRelated/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php(66): Google\Task\Runner->run()
#4 /www/cgi-bin/GoogleRelated/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php(922): Google\Http\REST::execute()
#5 /www/cgi-bin/GoogleRelated/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Service/Resource.php(238): Google\Client->execute()
#6 /www/cgi-bin/GoogleRelated/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Drive/Resource/Files.php(205): Google\Service\Resource->call()
#7 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook(592): Google\Service\Drive\Resource\Files->get()
#8 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook(80): getRootFolderId()
#9 {main}
  thrown in /www/cgi-bin/GoogleRelated/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php on line 134
```

Using a different project JSON file, I have a working script that successfully executes the same exact code (and so much more).

Since it seems impossible to have a google drive that lacks "root" folder (hence, the error message sounds misleading), I figure the issue here is in the scopes used or in the project itself, but I cannot see any problem with my current selection or the project attributes.  I've looked at answers like: [this one, for java](https://Google%20Drive%20API%20v3%20getting%20root%20folder%20Id%20in%20java) that pretty much says this is the right approach, and not found a better way to accomplish what I need here.

The scopes I'm requesting are:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata"
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder"
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.resource"
```

Really, I have three questions.

First is whether the issue might be scopes-related

Second is whether the above list lacks anything I need

Third, is there a way to see what scopes were actually granted, rather than only what was requested?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected answer, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer to 1st question

> First is whether the issue might be scopes-related

From your showing script and scopes, I'm worried that your current issue might be due to `First is whether the issue might be scopes-related`. From `$rootResult = $service->files->get('root')` and the ID of `0AORSlah_iew_Uk9PVA`, it seems that you are trying to retrieve the metadata of the root folder ID. I thought that in the case of your current scopes, the file metadata of the files created by the client can be retrieved by `drive.file`. But, in this case, I thought that the root folder cannot be retrieved, because the root folder is not created by the client.

In this case, how about adding a scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`? Or, how about replacing `drive.file` to `drive.metadata.readonly` or `drive.readonly`?

#### Answer to 2nd question

> Second is whether the above list lacks anything I need

In this case, I have no information on the actual goal of your script. So, I cannot answer whether the scopes of "drive.appdata", "drive.appfolder", "drive.resource" are required to be used. But. if you are not required to retrieve only the files except for the files created by your current client, I think that `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` is not required to be used.

If you want to retrieve only the file metadata of your Google Drive, I think that just `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` might be able to be used. In this case, the metadata of the root folder can be also retrieved.

#### Answer to 3rd question

> Third, is there a way to see what scopes were actually granted, rather than only what was requested?

If you want to confirm the scopes of your access token, how about using the following endpoint?

```bash
curl "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token={your access token}"
```

By this, you can see the current scopes of the access token.

Comment: Thanks, @Tanaike.  You've answered many questions for me. This is solved now, so you don't need to reply.  But I will say one of my questions was unclear.  For question 2, I meant to ask "Are the given scopes enough to allow me to use files->get() successfully."  And apparently the answer is 'no.'  I solved this by adding the blanket https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive to the scopes.  I'm sure your answers would have done it too, but the combination of things to try was too much.  .../auth/drive does what I need.

Comment: @Dennis Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the scope of `www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, in this case, the files and folders can be retrieved and updated. This can be also used for retrieving the file metadata. By the way, now, I also added a tag of `google-drive-api` for the users who have the same issue.